# where can I upload exe in azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

trying to follow along this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-dotnet-migrating-console-apps

I am stuck where it says "go to your function's "Your Files > Upload Files" (top right) and upload the 3 files in the code sample along with the .exe (and .dll's it requires)". I don't see that option for me. I have azure through VS professional subscription. This is what I see, can't figure out where to upload files?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Classic UI

This tutorial uses old UI. You can switch to it by clicking "Switch to classic expirience" in "overview" tab:

[image]

### New UI

In new UI try using KUDU in "Advanced Tools" -> Debug Console -> CMD/Powershell -> Drag and Drop your file :

[image]
[image]

Or try "App service editor":

[image]
[image]